# How to set custom error messages for argparse python module

Tags: python, error-handling, argparse

I want to change default message for errors caused by typing wrong argument value or typing argument without any value.

I have code *test.py*:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-n',
                    '--number',
                    type=int,
                    help='Specify a number to print',
                    required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not args.number:
        print("Hello")
    else:
        print(args.number)
```

And when i'm typing **python test.py** i have output **Hello**

When i'm typing **python test.py --number 1** i have output **1**

But when i'm typing **python test.py --number** i've got:
*test.py: error: argument -n/--number: expected one argument*

But i want to have custom message in that output like "*Please write number to print*" - **How i can "catch" error from argparser and customize the message of it**

Also i want to have same error message when i'll get *invalid int value*

like in example:
 **python test.py --number k**

*test.py: error: argument -n/--number: invalid int value: 'k'*

And i want:
 **python test.py --number k**

*Please write number to print*

 **python test.py --number**

*Please write number to print*

Comment: The argparse docs tell us that errors (at least most) go through the `parse.error` and `parser.exit` methods.  You can customize those.  The message to the `invalid int` case could be changed by writing a `type` function that raises a `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` with the custom message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you can override the **error** method of the ArgumentParser class, you can see the argparse source code at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/argparse.py

```
#instead of doing this
parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()

#do this

class CustomArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser)
    def error(self, message):
        raise Exception('Your message')

#then use the new class

parser = CustomArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to [Carlos Correa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74395676/14849082) answer, you can instead set the parser object's error method directly using [MethodType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525069/how-is-types-methodtype-used).

```
import argparse, types

parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()

def custom_error(self, message):
    raise Exception('Your message')

# Set the object's error method directly
parser.error = types.MethodType(custom_error, parser)
```

This can avoid some of the clunkiness of creating a new class specifically for this purpose.